# Sencha ExtJS 4.2: how can I synchronize two combo editors in a grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to edit two columns of my grid using combos as editors, and I need the values shown in the second to be filtered accordingly to the value selected in the first one.
There is also the problem that I need to show the "bound" value (i.e. "description") instead of the Id, in the grid cell.
I prepared a (very simplified) fiddle to show the problem here

[Click here for the fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12hi)

Looking at the fiddle, I'd need to select the brand in the first combo and then a model in the second, but I should obviously find only the models from the selected brand in there.
How can I show the descriptive text in the cell?
How can I filter the second combo?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editing plugin has an [`beforeedit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing-event-beforeedit) event you can use, for example:

```
listeners: {
    beforeedit: function(editor, context) {
        var record = context.record;

         if (context.field !== 'modelId') {
             return;
         }

         models.clearFilter(true);

         models.filter({
             property: 'brandId',
             value: record.getId()
        });
    }
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12hn

Comment: Great thanks, but what about the shown value? (it shows the IDs anyway, not the text)

Comment: You can use a `renderer`.